# Play Framework not displaying Form.globalErrors

Tags: playframework

I have a UserRegistration.java class

```
    package forms.account;

    import play.i18n.Messages;
    import play.data.validation.Constraints;
    import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;


    public class UserRegistration {

        @Required
        //@Constraints.MinLength(5)
        //@Constraints.MaxLength(25)
        public String fullname;

        @Constraints.Required
        //@Constraints.MinLength(5)
        //@Constraints.MaxLength(15)
        public String username;

        @Constraints.Required
        //@Constraints.Email
        public String email;

        @Constraints.Required
        //@Constraints.MinLength(8)
        public String password;

        @Constraints.Required
        //@Constraints.MinLength(8)
        public String repeatPassword;


        /**
         * Custom validation for fields in UserRegistration form
         * @return null if everything is ok otherwise returns the error message
         */
        public String validate(){

            // check if the two passwords match
            if(!password.equals(repeatPassword)){
                System.out.println(Messages.get("registration.password.nomatch"));
                return Messages.get("registration.password.nomatch");
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Correspondingly I have a register.scala.html file

```
    @(registrationForm: Form[forms.account.UserRegistration])

    @import helper._



    @main(null) {

        <h1>Product form</h1>
        @form(controllers.account.routes.UserRegistrationController.save()) {

        @if(registrationForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
            <p class="error">
                <span class="label label-danger">@registrationForm.globalError.message</span>
            </p>
        }

        <fieldset>

            <legend>User (@registrationForm("username").valueOr("New"))</legend>
            @inputText(registrationForm("fullname"))
            @inputText(registrationForm("username"))
            @inputText(registrationForm("email"))
            @inputPassword(registrationForm("password"))
            @inputPassword(registrationForm("repeatPassword"))

        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        }

    }
```

The controller looks like below

```
    package controllers.account;

    import controllers.Application;
    import forms.account.UserRegistration;
    import play.data.Form;
    import play.mvc.Result;
    import play.mvc.Controller;
    import views.html.account.register;
    import static play.data.Form.form;

    public class UserRegistrationController extends Controller{

        public static Result index(){

            String email = ctx().session().get("email");
            if(email != null){

            }else{
                return ok(register.render(form(UserRegistration.class)));
                //return null;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static Result save(){

            Form<UserRegistration> registerForm = form(UserRegistration.class).bindFromRequest();

            System.out.println(registerForm.errors().toString());

            if (registerForm.hasErrors()) {
                System.out.println("Form has errors");
                return badRequest(register.render(registerForm));
            }

            System.out.println("Saving..");
            return ok(register.render(registerForm));
        }

    }
```

The contents of the routes file is

```
    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

    GET     /                                               controllers.account.UserRegistrationController.index()
    POST    /UserRegistrationController                     controllers.account.UserRegistrationController.save()
```

The problem is no validation errors are getting printed when badRequest is being returned through UserRegistrationController.java file although validation errors are getting printed in the console

Answer (score 2):

Using all your code as is, except changing your `register.scala.html` view to the following:

```
@main(null) {
    <h1>Product form</h1>
    @form(routes.UserRegistrationController.save()) {

        @if(registrationForm.hasErrors) {
            <div class="alert alert-error">
            @if(registrationForm.errors.size() > 0) {
                @for((key, value) <- registrationForm.errors) {
                    @for(err <- value) {
                        <p>@key.toString() &rarr; @err.message()</p>
                    }
                }
            } else {No error returned.}
            </div>
        }

        <fieldset>
            <legend>User (@registrationForm("username").valueOr("New"))</legend>
            @inputText(registrationForm("fullname"))
            @inputText(registrationForm("username"))
            @inputText(registrationForm("email"))
            @inputPassword(registrationForm("password"))
            @inputPassword(registrationForm("repeatPassword"))
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
}
```

results in the following output:

[image: Form errors displayed]

I'm assuming the errors displayed below **Product Form** were what you were looking for.